# Rails conditional get (development mode) still returning "Not Modified" (`#fresh_when()`)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Why does the following (in development mode) incorrectly return "304 not modified" - should not such features be disabled by default in Rails when running in development mode?

My controller looks like this:

```
class WidgetController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
    fresh_when(etag: etag_for(@widget), last_modified: @widget.updated_at)
  end

  private

    def etag_for(*args)
      args.flatten + [current_user, last_deploy]
    end

    def last_deploy
      `git log --pretty=format:%H`.chomp
    end

end
```

I'm not clear on why in `Development` mode in my Rails application, this would be returning "304 Not Modified" headers, I thought that according to development mode, such things were not enabled?

I'm using the thin webserver, locally, which I suppose is slightly unusual, otherwise this is a typical application with no special conditions, or cases running on `Rails 3.1.1`

Comment: I'm having a similar problem on Rails 3.1.3. I'm using `fresh_when :etag` for caching. Although in development mode and with `config.middleware.delete Rack::ConditionalGet` and `config.middleware.delete Rack::ETag` I still get cached responses. Do you have any additional ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer was easier than that:

In `./config/environments/development.rb` I added the line:

```
  config.middleware.delete(Rack::ConditionalGet)
```

I filed this "bug" with Rails to get an official response, the issue can be found [here at their Github issue tracker](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3583).

Comment: Lee, I also ran into the issue. I don't understand why it would be on in development either. Have you tried your solution for Rails 4? It's not working for me.

Comment: I haven't John, but perhaps the middleware was renamed? Run `rake middleware` and see if any suspects look ripe for being deleted using my technique.

Comment: Another handy workaround is just to disable your Cache in the Chrome/Firebug debug tools.

Answer (score 0):

`fresh_when` is not altered by the environment. Per [the source for fresh_when](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/conditional_get.rb#L26)

```
def fresh_when(options)
  options.assert_valid_keys(:etag, :last_modified, :public)

  response.etag          = options[:etag]          if options[:etag]
  response.last_modified = options[:last_modified] if options[:last_modified]
  response.cache_control[:public] = true if options[:public]

  head :not_modified if request.fresh?(response)
end
```

And then the source for [request.fresh?](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/cache.rb#L28)

```
def fresh?(response)
  last_modified = if_modified_since
  etag          = if_none_match

  return false unless last_modified || etag

  success = true
  success &&= not_modified?(response.last_modified) if last_modified
  success &&= etag_matches?(response.etag) if etag
  success
end
```

What you could do, though, is to add a random number (or timestamp) to the etag in development mode, to force each request to be fresh.

Comment: Thanks chris, I did look at the implementation, didn't know if there could be configuration elsewhere, as in the middleware stack are `use Rack::ConditionalGet` and `use Rack::ETag`, these could also inherit the `RAILS_ENV` (more likely `RACK_ENV`) and decide whether to perform or not? I can't believe conditionalget is enabled in development mode, if it is, that sounds like a bug in Rails to me, as it prevents the easy code, safe, refresh cycle inherent to the successof Rails?